# std::function as sighandler_t

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, function-pointers

How to specify lambda, std::bind result or any other std::function as argument for unix signal function?

I'm trying the following

```
std::function<void(int)> handler1 = std::bind(&cancellation_token::cancel, &c);
std::function<void(int)> handler2 = [&c](int) { c.cancel(); };
```

but it doesn't work, because both

```
handler1.target<void(int)>()
```

and

```
handler2.target<void(int)>()
```

`return null`

It works if I initialize handler with free function pointer

```
void foo(int) { ... }
std::function<void(int)> handler = foo;
```

but this is absolutely useless. I need to capture some local variables, so I need either bind or lambda.

Actually I understand why it doesn't work. Documentation says that `target` function returns a pointer to the stored function if `target_type() == typeid(T)`, otherwise a null pointer. I don't understand how to make it work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's constructed by `bind`, or lambda with captured-data, you cannot convert it to free function, since `target` function works by `typeid`, `std::function` saves it in runtime, not for type `T`, with which `function` is templated. For `std::bind` it will be some library-type and for lambda it will be some unnamed type.

Comment: OK. Is there any other way to capture local variables in SIGINT handler?

Comment: @axe only by gloval variables.

Comment: OK. I changed the code to use static member variable instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dispatcher-like approach associating signal numbers to `std::function`s through a map.

You just need a map to hold the `std::function`s accesible from a free function:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::function<void(int)>> signalHandlers;
```

And a generic handler (free function) to map the signal number to the function:

```
void dispatcher(int signal) {
  // this will call a previously saved function
  signalHandlers.at(signal)(signal);
}
```

---

### Implementation example

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <csignal>
#include "cppsignal.hpp"

int main() {
  bool stop = false;
  // set a handler as easy as this
  CppSignal::setHandler(SIGINT, [&stop] (int) { stop = true; });

  while (!stop) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  }
  std::cout << "Bye" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

*cppsignal.cpp*

```
#include <cstring> // strsignal
#include <csignal>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <mutex>
#include "signal.hpp"

namespace CppSignal {

std::timed_mutex signalHandlersMutex;
std::unordered_map<int, std::function<void(int)>> signalHandlers;

// generic handler (free function) to set as a handler for any signal
void dispatcher(int signal) {
  std::unique_lock<std::timed_mutex> lock(signalHandlersMutex, std::defer_lock);
  if (!lock.try_lock_for(std::chrono::seconds(1))) {
    // unable to get the lock. should be a strange case
    return;
  }
  auto it = signalHandlers.find(signal);
  if (it != signalHandlers.end()) {
    it->second(signal);
  }
}

void registerHandler(int signal, const std::function<void(int)>& handler) {
  std::lock_guard<std::timed_mutex> lock(signalHandlersMutex);
  signalHandlers.emplace(signal, handler);
}

// this is the only method you will use
void setHandler(int signal, const std::function<void(int)>& handler, int flags) {
  // configure sigaction structure
  struct sigaction action;
  if (sigfillset(&action.sa_mask) == -1) {
    throw std::runtime_error("sigfillset failed");
  }
  action.sa_flags = flags;
  action.sa_handler = dispatcher;

  // set handler for the signal
  if (sigaction(signal, &action, nullptr) == -1 && signal < __SIGRTMIN) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Fail at configuring handler for signal: " + std::string(strsignal(signal)));
  }
  registerHandler(signal, handler);
}

}
```

*cppsignal.hpp*

```
#ifndef __CPPSIGNAL_HPP
#define __CPPSIGNAL_HPP

#include <functional>

namespace CppSignal {

void setHandler(int signal, const std::function<void(int)>& handler, int flags=0);

}

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

sighandler_t is defined to be a pointer to a function with the following definition:

```
void func(int);
```

Since std::bind and lambdas return functors, it is not possible to directly use them as signal handler. As a workaround you can use your own wrapper functions like

```
class SignalHandlerBase
{
public:
  virtual void operator(int) = 0;
};

template <class T>
class SignalHandler : public SignalHandlerBase
{
  T t;
public:
  SignalHandler(T _t) : t(_t) { }
  void operator(int i)
  {
    t(i);
  } 
};

class SignalManager
{
  int sig;
  SignalHandlerBase *shb;
  static void handlerFunction(int i)
  {
    shb(i);
  }
public:
  SignalManager(int signal) : sig(signal), shb(nullptr) { signal(signal, &handlerFunction); }
  template <class T>
  void installHandler(T t)
  {
    delete shb;
    shb = new SignalHandler<T>(t);
  }
};
```

Use global instances of `SignalManager` to manage individual signals

Comment: It would be a good idea to delay the call to `signal` until a signal handler is actually installed, and to unhook the signal on destruction of the `SignalManager`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was just meant as a simple example. It should also probably return the old handler when installing a new one

Answer (score 1):

C++11 1.9 [intro.execution]/6:

> When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt of a signal, the values of objects which
>   are neither
>
> - of type `volatile std::sig_atomic_t` nor
> - lock-free atomic objects (29.4)
>
> are unspecified during the execution of the signal handler, and the value of any 
>   object not in either of these
>   two categories that is modified by the handler becomes undefined.

The only action you can realistically take portably in a signal handler is to change the value of a flag whose type is `volatile std::sig_atomic_t` or a **lock-free** `std::atomic` (Note that not all `std::atomic` objects are lock-free). Non-signal handling code can then poll that flag to respond to the occurrence of the signal.

[N3787](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3787.html) has some interesting discussion about how to fix C++11 basically breaking signal handlers as a concept.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using std::atomic_bool, but that was not the question.